# How to select every year from a particular year to the current year as different rows?

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services

Say my start year is 2000 and I would like to have a one column select return every year from 2000 to the current year, example:

```
2000
2001
...
2012
2013
```

This is to populate a parameter in Reporting Services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing for you to do would be to create a [numbers table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11506/why-are-numbers-tables-invaluable) that you would use for these types of queries.

You could also use a recursive Common Table Expression to generate the list of years:

```
;with cte (yr) as
(
  select 2000
  union all
  select yr + 1
  from cte
  where yr+1 <=2013
)
select yr
from cte;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/15837)

Comment: I don't really understand the concept or the sql you provided, but it works like a charm and that's all I care about right now. Thank you!

Comment: @jreed121 Here is the link to the MSDN docs -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx  -- that talks about recursive queries.